# Binding a remote Service (AIDL)

Tags: android

There are dozens of questions around StackOverflow and guides across the internet, including Android's own documentation on getting this particular functionality working.

I believe I have followed all instruction and nuance to the letter, but here are some reference questions that I've used to try to tackle my problem:

[AIDL interface between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656689/aidl-interface-between-two-applications)
[Service not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339024/service-not-binding)
[Android: Binding to a remote service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728597/android-binding-to-a-remote-service)

The issue I'm encountering is that the Service itself cannot be located. Whether it is already running or not, I encounter the following error:

`Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.dumpsterfire/.DumpsterService } U=0: not found`

Here are the relevant configurations for the two apps

#### DumpsterFire (server/Service source)

**build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.dumpsterfire"
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree("/libs") { include("*.jar", "*.aar") })

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0")
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dumpsterfire">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DumpsterFire">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".DumpsterService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**DumpsterService.kt**

```kotlin
class DumpsterService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        return object : IDemoAidl.Stub() {
            override fun printAcross(message: String?) {
                Log.d("chaser", "Hello, I've been instructed to say:\n$message")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**IDemoAidl.aidl**

```java
interface IDemoAidl {
    void printAcross(String message);
}
```

#### ClientDumpster (client/Service binder)

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
//...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //...
    bindService(
            Intent().setClassName("com.example.dumpsterfire", ".DumpsterService"),
            connection,
            BIND_AUTO_CREATE
    )
}

val connection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
        IDemoAidl.Stub.asInterface(service)
                .printAcross("Assuming direct control")
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
        Log.d("chaser", "host service terminated")
    }
}
//...
```

**IDemoAidl.aidl**

```java
interface IDemoAidl {
    void printAcross(String message);
}
```

---

*P.S.* I have attempted to have the Service in question already running in the background, and verified its existence through the adb shell command `dumpsys activity services`. It doesn't change the error I receive.

*P.P.S.* I have also tried:

- Reinstalling both apps from scratch.
- Doing clean builds.
- Invalidate caches/Restart.

Comment: Did you tried to use full class name?

Comment: @Selvin Do you mean like `Intent().setClassName("com.example","com.example.DumpsterService")`? If so, yes, I have. It emits the same exact error.

Comment: Another idea is had you ever run any activity from "server" app before using client? I'm pretty sure that services and broadcast receivers are disabled before user run activity

Comment: @Selvin Yes, the `DumpsterFire` app has an activity and has previously been installed/launched before `DumpsterClient` is installed/launched.

Comment: Are you sure that `com.example` is applicationId in `DumpsterFire`.. I mean you can have id `whatever.you.want` and "java" package `something.really.different`... I don't know maybe you have postfix in gradle

Comment: I'm certain of the packages. But I can post the full manifests and `build.gradle` files if it will help. To be clear, I've explicitly run `DumpsterService` from `DumpsterFire` and actually verified its existence with `dumpsys activity services | grep com.example`. The output service package was in alignment with the package I've detailed here.

Comment: @Selvin I've updated the AndroidManifest in the `DumpsterFire` project and added the full contents of its build script. I did notice that I'd produced a typo in the package illustrated in the post, and I corrected it in both the project and here. Correcting the typo did not fix the issue.

Comment: I once had similar issue and I ended up using full component name, try `setClassName("com.example.dumpsterfire", "com.example.dumpsterfire.DumpsterService")`

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, that produces the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing this on Android 11, your problem may be that your client app cannot see the service app. To get [this sample service client](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/EmbedClient) to find [this sample service](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/EmbedServer) on Android 11, I needed to add a `<queries>` element to my client's manifest, with the package of the service app:

```
<queries>
  <package android:name="com.commonsware.android.r.embed.server" />
</queries>
```

Comment: Mark, you're some kind of super hero when it comes to Android stuff. Thank you so much for this. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Here's a link to the Android documentation on this functionality, in case anyone was looking for it: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#declare-other-apps

Comment: @nukeforum: Thanks for the kind words! I remembered banging my head against a wall for a couple of hours, wondering why the two apps couldn't see each other, when I was writing these samples. The behavior is seriously unintuitive.

Comment: I guess this is exactly why I need to read *all* the docs whenever a new version of Android drops. :P

Comment: @nukeforum: I'm gonna just drop [this](https://commonsware.com/R/) right here. 